# What makes bjobs to move from run to done state?

Tags: linux, unix, ibm-cloud, centos7

In my Linux machine , there are 2 bjobs created they are in run state hours together but output for that job is available and it is fine. I have to do some other operation if bjobs goes to done state . But it is not going to done state. What can cause this issue.

Comment: This is completely dependent on the code for the jobs

Comment: Can u please elaborate, because I am just user who writes some .pl script . In that script a job is assigned to open a tool and run some simple code .after all bjobs are done concatenate results.I observe tool is closed output is generated but still bjob is running.not going to done state.

Comment: Is there a way to set condition in command itself to move from run to done state. Else where to change or any debug steps to understand for which condition bjob is waiting for

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.